# Loop in R using a csv list

Tags: r, loops, filter

I have 27 csv files, one for each country. I need to creat a loop for: read each one of them, select the columns i want, filter one of that columns for "X" and then export to CSV.

I'm using these commands for now, but i don't know how to "loop" this:

```
df <- read.csv("Files.csv")

dfColum <- df[c("Colum1", "Colum2",...)]

dfColumFilter <- dfSemCol[dfColum$YEAR == "2023",]

write.csv(dfColumFilter, file = "C:/Users/.../Doc.csv")
```

Comment: The answers provide some options, it may also be helpful to read [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227) where they discuss a related issue and how to work with multiple frames in one `list`. (Not a prefect solution for your question but provides some relevant context.)

Answer (score 1):

```
all_files <- c("file1.csv", "file2.csv", ...)  # Could generate with list.files()

for (file in all_files) {
  df            <- read.csv(file)
  dfColum       <- df[c("Colum1", "Colum2", ...) ]
  dfColumFilter <- dfSemCol[dfColum$YEAR == "2023",]
  write.csv(dfColumFilter, file = paste0("C:/Users/.../Doc", file, ".csv"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `lapply`.

- First get the file list with `list.files(pattern="files.*csv")`,
- then read the files and filter the columns with `read.csv(x)[,c("Column1", "Column2")]`,
- finally filter the rows with `res[res$YEAR == 2023,]` and write the output.

```
lapply(list.files(pattern="files.*csv"), \(x){
  res <- read.csv(x)[,c("YEAR", "Column1", "Column2")]
  write.csv(file = paste0("Doc_", x), res[res$YEAR == 2023,])})
```